# Javascript slideshow in random order

Tags: javascript, slideshow

My slideshow displays images in an non-random order at the moment, but I'd like it to be random.

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6hCaJ/

Javascript:

```
function loadNextImage(useRandomSelection) {    
    if(imagePool.length > 0) {
        if(useRandomSelection) {
            var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * imagePool.length);
            var imgData = imagePool.splice(randomIndex,1);
        } else {
            var imgData = imagePool.shift();
        }

        $(".back-image-container").append("<img id='back-image-" + imgData.id + "' class='back-image' src='" + imgData.url + "'/>");

        var imgObj = $("#back-image-" + imgData.id);        
        imgObj.hide();

        if ( imgObj.complete || imgObj.readyState == 4 || imgObj.readyState == "complete") {
            loadCompleted(imgObj,useRandomSelection);
        } else {
            imgObj.load(function() {
                loadCompleted(imgObj,useRandomSelection);     
            });
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="back-image-container">
    <img id="back-image-0" class="back-image" src="http://cdn2.bigcommerce.com/n-pktq5q/b2aus7wd/product_images/theme_images/scorpiongoldberlin.jpg?t=1403886381" style="width: 1347px; height: 898px; left: -63px; display: inline;">
    <img id="back-image-1" class="back-image" src="http://cdn2.bigcommerce.com/n-pktq5q/b2aus7wd/product_images/theme_images/brelingirlcross2.jpg?t=1403886381" style="width: 1347px; height: 898px; left: -63px; display: none;">
    <img id="back-image-2" class="back-image" src="http://cdn2.bigcommerce.com/n-pktq5q/b2aus7wd/product_images/theme_images/brelinafternoon.jpg?t=1403886381" style="width: 1347px; height: 898px; left: -63px; display: none;">
</div>
```

Comment: What's your question, exactly?

Comment: I'd like to make my javascript slideshow to display images randomly.

Comment: Yes, but you've got a script to do that already, and you're not telling us what's wrong with it.  You expect us to not only answer your question, but figure out what the question is?

Comment: What happens when you run your script?  What's the symptom?  What have you tried to figure out/fix it?

Comment: The script doesn't work. The images are played in order (back-image-0, back-image-2, back-image-2, ...)

Comment: Well, that's a little more helpful.  Still, there's not enough information to fix your problem here.  I played around with it, but there's not enough context.  There's nothing wrong with your random selection code, but I don't know what `loadCompleted` does, nor do I know what's in `imagePool` other than what I can infer from your code.  Try posting a jsFiddle.

Comment: @EthanBrown Please see the jsfiddle I added in the posts. I think I've kind of succeeded in copying it on jsfiddle. It's a bigcommerce site, so the jsfiddle is not exactly the same as the code that I have on the live server for the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the problem is in `loadNextImage`, but the way it is called. Notice `loadNextImage` has a parameter that defines if the order should be random or not.

In your fiddle the call to `loadNextImage` is done as such:

```
loadNextImage(false);
```

This means the random behavior is bypassed. Try simply inverting the boolean value:

```
loadNextImage(true);
```

Also, this line seems to have an error:

```
var imgData = imagePool.splice(randomIndex,1);
```

[splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) returns an array of the results removed, because there can be more than one. In this case it is returning an array with a single item, the image data shifted. To fix this reference you need to get the first element of this array:

```
var imgData = imagePool.splice(randomIndex,1)[0];
```

With these changes the slide functions correctly.